# C#: In which classes are the ICommandExecutor interface used?

Tags: c#, winforms, command

I found the ICommandExecutor interface in .net but cant find the classes where it is implemented. I know there is some xaml related stuff where it's used. But is there something for the winforms, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's implemented in MenuItemData which is an inner class of System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.

In general if you're looking to find out what interefaces are implemented where, the quickest way to get the answer is via Reflector.  It makes queries like this incredibly easy.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Uhm, I was hopeing that there is more use of the Command design pattern in .net
But the hint with reflector is very great.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the Command design pattern, but it was not the intent to be used. That's why the vendor tells us no to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.icommandexecutor(VS.85).aspx.

It should be done in a way to be used since it's a common artifact in every UI oriented application that is based on design patterns.

Ciao.